# Is there a data collection backend for Tensorflow Lite apps?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Training deep learning models from scratch requires very large datasets. Even fine tuning existing pre-trained models can require many examples from the target classes. When a tensorflow-lite based app is used in the field it is likely being exposed to a new and useful set of inputs which could serve as additional training data if they were captured.

Is there a working example of app level code and backend stack which does this capture and storage?

Comment: Not at this time, but distributed and federated learning is obviously an exciting new avenue of work, and are quite interested in the possibility